# Connect to single table within a MSSQL database or terminate connection to database once layer added to QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, sql-server, connection

I'm connecting to MSSQL server '123' that contains 100s of databases and I am connecting to just database 'ABC'. 'ABC' contains roughly ~700 tables.  Once I add the 'xyzTable' as a layer to my QGIS project, the connection to the ~700 other tables in 'ABC' remains.  This is putting unnecessary resource strain on the 'ABC' database and '123' server.

Is there anyway to only connect to the table(s) I need from 'ABC'? Or is there a way to terminate the connection to all the other ~700 tables in 'ABC' without closing out QGIS and reopening the project.